# Retrieve MySQL row key

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to retrieve a row from a MySQL database which returns a row, for example, with the corresponding key. Right now, retrieving a row simply gives an array in PHP when printed as such:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 15
    [1] => 2011-02-27 22:31:46
    [2] => salmon-with-pineapple-curry-sauce-photo_0.jpg
    [3] => 1
    [4] => Salmon Fillet
    [5] => Trader Joes
    [6] => So delicious
    [7] => 5
    [8] => 35.282753
    [9] => -120.659615
)
```

how would I retrieve so that the key is the name of the field in the database so that when I go to use the json_encode function, the key is associated with the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)  which returns the rows as an array indexed with DB table field

Output array will looks like this

```
Array
(
    ['id'] => 15
    ['date'] => 2011-02-27 22:31:46
    ['name'] => salmon-with-pineapple-curry-sauce-photo_0.jpg
    .....
    .....//other elements or fields
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This function is probably what you are looking for: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mysql_fetch_array` with `MYSQL_ASSOC` option, or `mysql_fetch_assoc`...

http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array

http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc

Answer (score 1):

Use the `mysql_fetch_assoc` to get an associated array with the results.  That should give you what you want.

Link : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php